# IIS7 URL 301 Redirect folder and domain

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying (and epicly failing) to figure out the necessary rules to achieve the following as permanent 301 redirects:

```
www.mysite.com                    > mysite.com
mysite.com/oldfolder              > mysite.com
www.mysite.com/oldfolder          > mysite.com
mysite.com/oldfolder/old-file     > mysite.com/old-file
www.mysite.com/oldfolder/old-file > mysite.com/old-file
```

If anyone with an understanding of IIS7 rewrite module could help out I'd be very grateful!

Comment: For context, we're moving from what was a wordpress blog in a subdirectory to being in the root but also wanting to redirect from the canonical subdomain(s) to root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference and for anyone else doing a similar thing here's the total rules we ended up using:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <!--To always remove trailing slash from the URL-->
            <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)/$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <!-- redirects blog/2012/10/post to /post. -->
            <rule name="Redirect blog with dates to root" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^blog/([0-9]+)/([_0-9]+)/(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?mydomain.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:0}/{R:3}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <!-- redirects blog/post to /post. -->
            <rule name="Redirect blog to root" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^blog/(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?mydomain.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:0}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <!-- redirects case-studies/case-study to /case-study. -->
            <rule name="Case studies redirect." stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^case-studies/(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?mydomain.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:0}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <!-- for SEO the www is stripped from the URL. -->
            <rule name="Canonical host name.">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain\.com$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <!-- removes index.php from the URL. -->
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just have to add a rule like so:

Requested URL:
Matches the Pattern

Using: Regular Expressions

Pattern:
oldfolder

Ignore Case: true

Action type: redirect

redirect URL: htt://www.mysite.com

Append query string : false
redirect type 301